# load parquet file and keep same number hdfs partitions

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a parquet file `/df` saved in hdfs with 120 partitions.  The size of each partition on hdfs is around 43.5 M.

Total size

```
hdfs dfs -du -s -h /df
5.1 G  15.3 G  /df
```

```
hdfs dfs -du -h /df
43.6 M  130.7 M  /df/pid=0
43.5 M  130.5 M  /df/pid=1
...
43.6 M  130.9 M  /df/pid=119
```

I want to load that file into Spark and keep the same number of partitions.
However, Spark will automatically load the file into 60 partitions.

```py
df = spark.read.parquet('df')
df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

```
60
```

---

**HDFS settings:**

`'parquet.block.size'` is not set.

```py
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('parquet.block.size')
```

returns nothing.

'dfs.blocksize' is set to 128.

```py
float(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get("dfs.blocksize"))/2**20
```

returns

```
128
```

Changing either of those values to something lower does not result in the parquet file loading into the same number of partitions that are in hdfs.

For example:

```py
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().setInt("parquet.block.size", 64*2**20)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().setInt("dfs.blocksize", 64*2**20)
```

---

I realize 43.5 M is well below 128 M.  However, for this application, I am going to immediately complete many transformations that will result in each of the 120 partitions getting much closer to 128 M.

I am trying to save myself having to repartition in the application imeadiately after loading.

Is there a way to force Spark to load the parquet file with the same number of partitions that are stored on the hdfs?

Comment: what if you try setting this parameter? to 43.5MB (43500000 bytes) ```spark.conf.set("spark.files.maxPartitionBytes", 43500000)```

Comment: Nope.  Still pulls it into 60 partitions.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd start from checking on how Spark splits the data into partitions.
By default it depends on the nature and size of your data & cluster. 
This article should provide you with the answer why your data frame was loaded to 60 partitions:

https://umbertogriffo.gitbooks.io/apache-spark-best-practices-and-tuning/content/sparksqlshufflepartitions_draft.html

In general - its **Catalyst** who takes care of all the optimization (including number of partitions), so unless there is really a good reason for custom settings, I'd let it do its job. If any of the transformations you use are wide, Spark will shuffle the data anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I can use the `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` property to keep the partition sizes where I want when importing.

The [Other Configuration Options documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#other-configuration-options) for the `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` property states:

> The maximum number of bytes to pack into a single partition when reading files. This configuration is effective only when using file-based sources such as Parquet, JSON and ORC.

Example (where `spark` is a working `SparkSession`):

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", 67108864) ## 64Mbi
```

To control the number of partitions during transformations, I can set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`, for which the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#other-configuration-options) states:

> Configures the number of partitions to use when shuffling data for joins or aggregations.

Example (where `spark` is a working `SparkSession`):

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 500)
```

Additionally, I can set `spark.default.parallelism`, for which the [Execution Behavior documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior) states:

> Default number of partitions in RDDs returned by transformations like join, reduceByKey, and parallelize when not set by user.

Example (where `spark` is a working `SparkSession`):

```
spark.conf.set("spark.default.parallelism", 500)
```