# Repartitioning prior to saving a DataFrame into parquet format necessary?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-partitioning

I am having multiple `DataFrames (DFs)`, storing monthly data of customers for the last 5 years. Some `DFs` store `Revenue` information, other stores `Complaints` data and so on. All these DataFrames are `Customer ID` and `Month` based, as you can see in the example dataset below -

```
df_revenue.show(100)
    +-----------+-----------+--------+-- ....--+-------+
    |Customer_ID|       City| Revenue|         |  Month|
    +-----------+-----------+--------+-- ....  +-------+
    |      60012|     Berlin|   24.64|         |JAN2017|
    |      60012|     Berlin|   33.00|         |FEB2017|
    |      60012|     Berlin|   44.76|         |MAR2017|
    ....
    ....
    ....
    |      58937|   Hannover|  101.32|         |JAN2016|
    |      58937|   Hannover|   66.72|         |APR2016|
    |      58937|   Hannover|  190.50|         |AUG2018|
    |      58937|   Hannover|   89.71|         |DEC2018|
    ....
    +-----------+-----------+--------+-- ....--+-------+
```

**Ultimate aim** is to join these DataFrames for specified 12 month period. So, for `JUN2018`, we will **join** all these DataFrames by only taking respective data from Jul,2017 - Jun,2018 (*last 12 months*).

All these DataFrames, having complete 5 year data, have been stored in `parquet` formats `partitioned by` Month, as shown below -

```
df_revenue.write.format('parquet').partitionBy('Month').save('/../revenue')
```

Using [`partitionBy()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html) on `Month` makes it faster to extract the data for respective months from the `parquet` files, since the data is partitioned on `Month` basis in parquet files. Once these subset DataFrames, encompassing 12 month data, are extracted, we can join them by [repartitioning](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition) them first on `Customer_ID` basis and then joining them, so as to avoid shuffles (a costly operation indeed) as much as possible. Something like this -

```
df_revenue = spark.read.format('parquet')\
                       .load('/../revenue')\
                       .where((col('Month') >= lit('2017-07-01')) 
                                      & 
                             (col('Month') < lit('2018-06-30'))).\
                       .repartition(NumPartitions, 'Customer_ID')

df_complaints = .....
                       .repartition(NumPartitions, 'Customer_ID')
.
.
df_joined = df_revenue.join(df_complaints,['Customer ID'],how='left')
```

**My Question:** Since we are ultimately joining these subset DataFrames on `Customer ID` basis, so will it be of any help if we [`repartition()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition) the data by `Customer ID` before saving it as parquet files, like shown below?

```
df_revenue.repartition(n,'Customer_ID').write.format('parquet').partitionBy('Month').save('/../revenue')
```

The reason I am asking this is because I have noticed that once we load the DataFrame from the stored `parquet` files, the [number of partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602051/load-parquet-file-and-keep-same-number-hdfs-partitions) change and if it changes, then what is the use of `repartitioning` the DataFrame before saving it as `parquet` format in the very first place! I have seen so many posts on SO, where people `repartition()` the DataFrame first and then store it in parquet.

Any clarification would be very appreciated.